# Special format for an author's name in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

To use bold text format for an author's name in `biblatex` bibliography I use `\textbf{LastName,  FirstName, MiddleName}` command in bibliography database. I wonder if it is possible to use some special text format for an author's name in `biblatex` bibliography by defining some command in `LaTeX` preamble. Thanks

Something like this

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

Comment: For all authors, you might want to have a look at [Bold the last name of the first author in a biblatex bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167190/35864) or [Make author names bold in bibliography only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178862/35864); for specific authors: [Make specific author bold using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864). You should not use formatting directives like `\textbf` in the `author` field. The name format should be "Last, First Middle" or "First Middle Last".

Comment: The code you added to your question is exactly what I would use, if I wanted to have all names in bold. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to bold my name only.

Comment: Ahh, I see, then [Make specific author bold using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864) is what you need, you might also like [`biblatex-publist`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist) which draws from [biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509/35864).