# Bold the last names authors/editors in a biblatex bibliography (but only the ones in front of the title)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I use pdfLaTeX and bibLaTeX with biber as the backend. In my bibliography I want to bold the last names of all authors or editors; but not of the editors of a `@collection` if the entry is an `@incollection`. To put it differently, I want all the lastnames of the names that bibliography entries begin with in bold, but not the names that may follow the title of the entry. I found a similar question with solutions: [Bold the last name of the first author in a biblatex bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167190/bold-the-last-name-of-the-first-author-in-a-biblatex-bibliography).

How can I achieve such a result? As my knowledge of in-depth LaTeX is very limited and I can't change the macros given in the solutions (mentioned above) myself, I hope that somebody has a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This solution is now updated for `biblatex` >= 3.3, see the edit history for the pre-3.3 version.*

I follow my solution to [Bold the last name of the first author in a biblatex bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167190/35864), but make all authors bold. The only change is that now always have `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibbold{##1}}`, not only on the first name.

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-fb}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-fb}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibbold{##1}}%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-fb}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-fb}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibbold{##1}}%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,gaonkar:in,brandt}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you use a numeric style that does not use `sortname` you will also need

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given-fb}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family-given-fb}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{family-given-fb}
```