# Biblatex Bibliography: How to make year bold and put editor in parentheses?

Tags: biblatex

First question, so tell me all the things I do wrong!

So thanks to @moewe ([Bold the last names authors/editors in a biblatex bibliography (but only the ones in front of the title)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274768/bold-the-last-names-authors-editors-in-a-biblatex-bibliography-but-only-the-one?rq=1)) my bibliography looks almost as I want it to. Two more things:

a) how do I put the "editor"-remark (in my German example "Hrsg.") in parentheses, without the comma after the name

b) how do I make the year bold?

So now it looks like: **Lastname**, Firstname, Hrsg. (YEAR): [...]

It should look like: **Lastname**, Firstname (Hrsg.) (**YEAR**): [...]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, ngerman, headsepline]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%biblatex
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-icomp,
ibidpage=true,
natbib,
ibidtracker=true,
idemtracker=true,
maxbibnames=9,
maxcitenames=2,
dashed=false
]
{biblatex}

\addbibresource{lit_test.bib}

%divide names by slash
\let\oldmultinamedelim\multinamedelim
\let\oldfinalnamedelim\finalnamedelim
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}

%last name bold
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-fb}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-fb}{%
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibbold{##1}}%
    \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

%colon insted of period after year
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{document}

\cite{Hirsch}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example would be even better if you used `biblatex-exampes.bib` as `.bib` file instead of referring to your file `lit_test.bib` which we don't have. For future questions you might want to keep in mind that we prefer to ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following redefinitions of macros from `authoryear.bbx` to your preamble

The part for a) is a slightly modernised version of [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s answer to [biblatex: How to remove the comma before ed./eds.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30151/35864)

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{parensbold}{\mkbibparens{\mkbibbold{#1}}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parensbold]{%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
         {\printdateextralabel}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}}%
\makeatother
```